# How to create a dynamic labelset on Bokeh that will avoid text overlapping?

Tags: python, label, bokeh

I would like to create a Labelset on Bokeh that is going to define the best location in order to avoid the text overlapping.

I tried the following code without success:

```
labels = LabelSet(x='weight', y='height', text='Name', level='glyph',
              x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=source, render_mode='canvas')
```

[Example of what I do not want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jln8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.1 there is nothing built in to Bokeh that will automatically dodge labels. I think this would be a great feature but no one has had the opportunity to work on it yet. There is not a good answer for this currently, there is not much to suggest other than manual experimentation and placement of labels. (And even that can be thrown off if the plot allows zooming.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I will wait for an update;)

Comment: AFAIK there is no issue for it, so if you are interested in it becoming a feature please open a GitHub issue to discuss it, being detailed about proposed/preferred syntax, behavior, etc. https://github.com/issues