# Bokeh Annotation Overlapping Issue

Tags: python, annotations, visualization, bokeh

I am trying to plot a bubble chart in bokeh and adding the column labels as an annotation there using Labelset. Some of These Labels are getting overlapped to each other and creating visual clutter in the graph. Please guide me.
Here is the code looks like -

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, output_file
output_notebook()
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral10

df_dict = {
    'Plans': ['ABC ValueCharge', 'Bizbazar 200CarbonNatural', 'EqualiserClient SuperSaverCombo'],
    'Rating': [17, 15, 14],
    'Sales': [1330.443, 1312.271, 1312.168],
    'Spends': [72.49, 47.7, 13.2417514]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
p = figure(height = 600, width = 800, x_range = (0, 25), y_range = (800, 2000))
source = ColumnDataSource(data = df)

p.circle(x = 'Rating', y = 'Sales', size = 'Spends',source = source,alpha = 0.8
        )
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Rating"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Sales"
labels = LabelSet(x='Rating', y='Sales', text='Plans', source = source,
                  x_offset= -50, y_offset=10, text_font_size = '7pt')
p.add_layout(labels)

show(p)
```

Here is the visualization generated -

[image: Viz with overlapped annotation text]

similar to what i am trying to accomplish - [How to create a dynamic labelset on Bokeh that will avoid text overlapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56038533/how-to-create-a-dynamic-labelset-on-bokeh-that-will-avoid-text-overlapping)

i have already tried manual experimentation with x_offset, y_offset and label rotation to solve this issue, but none of them is working for me.

Comment: @Abhey Could you please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show your usecase? Without this information it would be just guessing.

Comment: @mosc9575 -  sure, i have edited my question and have added two images, the code and the result generated. in the visualization result there is an overlap of annotation labels and i wanted to remove this text overlap. so ideally, i am looking for an approach by which labelset can automatically dodge the text overlap or probably i can have some callout label kind of functionality .

Comment: Please do not post code as image. This is hard to copy'n'past.

Comment: @mosc9575 - sure, I have just added the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `x_offset` and `y_offset` for each label as you did for `x` and `y` in the `LabelSet` as long as you are using as `ColumnDataSource` as `source`. This gives you some freedom to move the in labels in different directions. There is also `text_align` which can be useful.

### Example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import output_notebook, show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral10
output_notebook()

df_dict = {
    'Plans': ['ABC ValueCharge', 'Bizbazar 200CarbonNatural', 'EqualiserClient SuperSaverCombo'],
    'Rating': [17, 15, 14],
    'Sales': [1330.443, 1312.271, 1312.168],
    'Spends': [72.49, 47.7, 13.2417514],
    'x_offset': [0, -50, 70],
    'y_offset': [45, -5, -5],
    'text_align': ['center', 'right', 'left']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
source = ColumnDataSource(data = df)

# figure
p = figure(
    height = 300,
    width = 500,
    x_range = (10, 20),
    y_range = (1300, 1350)
)

p.circle(x = 'Rating', y = 'Sales', size = 'Spends',source = source,alpha = 0.8
        )
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Rating"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Sales"
labels = LabelSet(
    x='Rating',
    y='Sales',
    text='Plans',
    x_offset= 'x_offset',
    y_offset='y_offset',
    text_font_size = '7pt',
    text_align='text_align',
    source = source,
)
p.add_layout(labels)

show(p)
```

### Output

[image: shifted lables]

### Comment

It is possible that the labels will be over and under each other if you use the zoom tools.

I hope this is a useable the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mosc9575, i'll surely try this, though i am still wondering if there is any other better way exist to solve this particular issue. because if i have more points in my bubble chart, it will be a cumbersome task to set this manually for each of the point and will involve a lot of manual experimentation. apart from that it will also mean, it's not possible to automate this task in future, if i want to.

Comment: You could add this information in a HoverTool. Then it is available when the mouse is over the point and the labels can't be on top of each other.